# Serial Transactions on Select query

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I am using spring jpa .

I have series of select statements based on same column within same transaction ,
suppose

```
select * from emp where status='active' and emp_id=1;
update emp set status='inactive' where emp_id=1;
```

after above statements executed with in same transaction i have one more select statement which run same select query but it should not give the emp_id 1 because its inactive.

i have tried @Transactional on update and @Transactional on Select state with isolation uncommitted but no luck.

Anyway to solve this problem by isolation levels?

Comment: your second select query - is it also in same transaction?
If so then it is expected behaviour right

Comment: If you want to read something from DB and update immediately and store back results,
you can use "SELECT for UPDATE " query which is better and works fine